# What impact does a car lease have on credit, if any?

Tags: credit-score

Does having any number of car leases impact one's credit score?

Does it count towards amount of credit debt I have and impact credit usage ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, a car lease is pretty much the same as a car loan for credit scoring purposes. Since payment history is the largest contributing factor to your credit score, timely lease payments are important.

Comment: Does it count towards amount of credit debt I have and impact credit usage ratio?

Comment: @trusktr Utilization is based solely on revolving credit accounts (credit cards/lines of credit), so any loan/lease/mortgage that has a specific end-date does not factor in to utilization.

Comment: @HartCO: That's not accurate.  Installment loan utilization is computed separately from revolving utilization, but it is computed and it does have an effect.

Comment: @BenVoigt According to all the sources I looked at, including Experian, only revolving credit accounts factor into credit utilization:  https://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/credit-education/score-basics/credit-utilization-rate/  It does say installment loans do factor in 'another way', just not credit utilization rate.

Comment: I'm not sure what this is if not a version of utilization rate specific to installment loans: "**Proportion of loan balances to loan amounts is too high**
FICO® Scores weigh the balances of mortgage and non-mortgage installment loans (such as auto or student loans) against the original loan amounts shown on a person’s credit report. Your score was impacted because your proportion of installment loan balances to the original loan amounts is too high."

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah that sure sounds like utilization to me too. Interesting that they bother to say it is specifically not part of credit utilization. Perhaps it's a much lower weighting than the revolving credit accounts so they keep it separate.

Comment: @HartCO: I think it has more to do with the fact that $$\frac{a + b}{c + d} \neq \mean( \frac{a}{c}, \frac{b}{d} )$$